# Executing copyFromLocal command from one machine to another machine

Tags: hadoop

I am executing following command:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /tmp/temp/pattern_BS.conf hdfs://wihadoopn301p.prod.ch3.s.com:/user/hdfs/hadoop/qa2/BS/
```

In this I am trying to copy `pattern_BS.conf` in `/tmp/temp` folder on local drive, into `hdfs://wihadoopn301p.prod.ch3.s.com:/user/hdfs/hadoop/qa2/BS/` location.

But it giving following error:

```
copyFromLocal: For input string: ""
Usage: java FsShell [-copyFromLocal <localsrc> ... <dst>]
```

Please help me out in solving this problem.

Comment: check source with ls command and check destination with hadoop fs -ls and use if they work properly

Comment: But both src and dest are valid. can u advice some more....\

Comment: I usually use this comman with out absolute path like just /qa2/BS/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the command as given below, because copyFromLocal expects first argument to be a local file and the second argument to be a location in hdfs

hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /tmp/temp/pattern_BS.conf /user/hdfs/hadoop/qa2/BS/